# c++ eigen 3.5, eigen maps don't use named return value optimisation?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm quite new to c++ and its eigen library. 
I've come across what I think is slightly strange behaviour when returning an eigen map (which points to a std::vector) from a function, or returning a std::vector from a function and then applying an eigen map to it. I think this is to do with named return value optimisation (NRVO).

I've had a play around with three methods of doing this. The first two give undesired results, while the third method gives the results I want (see output below).
Here is a minimum working example illustrating the three methods:

```
int main(){
    double i1 = 1, i2 = 2, i3 = 3, i4 = 4, i5 = 5, i6 = 6, i7 = 7, i8 = 8; 

    //method 1
    Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > x_m1 = get_map_test(i1, i2, i3, i4);
    Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > y_m1 = get_map_test(i5, i6, i7, i8); 

    //method 2
    Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > x_m2(get_vec_test(i1, i2, i3, i4).data(), 2, 2);
    Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > y_m2(get_vec_test(i5,i6,i7,i8).data(), 2, 2);

    //method 3
    std::vector<double> x_v3 = get_vec_test(i1, i2, i3, i4);
    std::vector<double> y_v3 = get_vec_test(i5, i6, i7, i8);
    Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > x_m3(x_v3.data(), 2, 2);
    Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > y_m3(y_v3.data(), 2, 2);
}  //end main

//used in method 1
Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > get_map_test(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    std::vector<double> t_v = {a,b,c,d};
    return Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd >(t_v.data(), 2, 2);
 }

 //used in methods 2 and 3
std::vector<double> get_vec_test(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    std::vector<double> t_v = {a,b,c,d};
    return t_v;
 }
```

## method 1:

I started by simply passing values to a function, then in the function, storing those values in a std::vector, and returning an eigen map (of an eigen matrix) pointing to this vector.

I then got the following output for the values of matrices x_m1 and y_m1, as well as their .data() values:

```
x_m1:
4.94066e-324            7
4.94066e-324            8
y_m1:
4.94066e-324            7
4.94066e-324            8
x_m1.data():
0xaea150
y_m1.data():
0xaea150
```

The output of the maps is clearly not what is desired. Furthermore, the maps shouldn't be pointing to the same vector.

## method 2:

Next I tried returning the std::vector, and using it to initialise a map in the same line as the function return.

The corresponding results are:

```
x_m2:
4.94066e-324            7
4.94066e-324            8
y_m2:
4.94066e-324            7
4.94066e-324            8
x_m2.data():
0xaea150
y_m2.data():
0xaea150
```

As can be seen, this leads to the same results, but I can sort of understand why NRVO doesn't take place here.

## method 3:

Finally I tried returning the vector, and then initialising the map on the following line:

```
x_m3:
1 3
2 4
y_m3:
5 7
6 8
x_m3.data():
0xaea150
y_m3.data():
0xaea180
```

This gives the result I want, and I guess NRVO on the std::vector is the reason why.

## attempt at understanding results:

As mentioned I think the determinant of whether the method gives the desired results is whether NRVO occurs or not.

For the third method I know that NRVO occurs for the std::vector.

I can see for the second method that perhaps the data in the vector is destroyed when the function exits so one is left with a 'dangling vector' in the calling function (thus I assume NRVO for std::vector only occurs when you are explicitly setting the function return equal to a vector of the same type as the return??). 
And since the data was destroyed, the same addresses can be used for the second function call to store the doubles (which suffers the same fate).

So I guess my main question (apart from clarification of the statements I just made) is, does NRVO not work for eigen maps? Is there any particular reason for this?

I'm using eigen 3.5, c++11 with g++

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with NRVO, it is about the lifetime of objects in C++ (no garbage collection there so you can easily have dangling pointers).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand that methods 1 and 2 lead to dangling pointers, what I don't understand is how this doesn't have anything to do with NRVO (see my second comment to Jacob's answer).

Comment: You can use `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable NRVO and help convince yourself that it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a brief look at the documentation for `Eigen::Map` it's my understanding that it's a non-owning wrapper around the data pointed to by the pointer you provide it. This lets you perform operations on this data without having to make additional copies of the data.

Looking at "method 1":

```
Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > get_map_test(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    std::vector<double> t_v = {a,b,c,d};
    return Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd >(t_v.data(), 2, 2);
}
```

You return an `Eigen::Map` where the pointer refers to the memory allocated by the vector `t_v`. When `t_v` goes out of scope at the end of the function, the memory is deallocated and but the `Eigen::Map` is still mapping the memory pointed to by the now-dangling pointer. Not good.

Method 2 looks like this:

```
std::vector<double> get_vec_test(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    std::vector<double> t_v = {a,b,c,d};
    return t_v;
}
```

Nothing bad will happen in this function itself. You're just making a vector of your 4 doubles and return it by value. However, you then do this with it:

```
Eigen::Map< Eigen::MatrixXd > x_m2(get_vec_test(i1, i2, i3, i4).data(), 2, 2);
```

The `std::vector<double>` object returned from `get_vec_test` is a temporary. You provide a pointer to the data in that temporary into `Eigen::Map`. At the end of evaluating the full expression `x_m2` is left with a dangling pointer as well, as the lifetime of the temporary `std::vector<double>` returned from `get_vec_test` ends and the memory allocated to the data is deallocated. Not good.

Of course method 3 avoids this entirely, as you store the vectors returned from `get_vec_test` for the lifetime of the `Eigen::Map`s using those vectors.

The problem you're seeing is unrelated to NRVO, and is all about understanding object lifetimes in C++. Your code is attempting to perform operations on objects that no longer exists, through pointers to those objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I guess like I eluded to, you are saying the behaviour is down to NRVO and it not occurring leading to dangling pointers. If this is the case, I guess my question becomes, is there any particular reason eigen maps don't use NRVO. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: The behavior has nothing to do with (N)RVO. Map<> is essentially a pointer, so in "method 1", `get_vec_test` is essentially returning `t_v.data()`, then `t_v` is deleted, and the returned pointer is dangling.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still can't think of this without RVO, so perhaps my understanding is incorrect: 
method 3: RVO occurs so the data the std::vector is pointing to is stored in memory with lifetime of the calling function (main), then the map is set to point to this. method 2: RVO doesn't occur so when the called function exits, the data being pointed to by the std::vector is destroyed, so that and the map are dangling. Method 1: apparently RVO doesn't occur so data pointed to by map and std::vector is destroyed when function exits, returning dangling map pointer.

Comment: @KamKam please forget about RVO and reread the answer. method 3: it doesn't matter if there is RVO or not, what matters is that x_v3 is a local object that remains alive until the end of the function. method 2: the vector that is returned is not stored anywhere, it is a temporary object and dies at the end of the line that defines x_m2. method 1: of course there is no RVO of an object of some type in a function that returns a different type...

Comment: The penny has finally started to drop and I think I understand. The reason why the data is destroyed in method 1 is because the eigen map is **non-owning** so when the std::vector is deallocated the memory is freed. Thanks for bearing with me people...